# How to use Typoscript conditions for page uid?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

How do I use conditions to put different headerdata on the home page and 3 other pages using typoscript?

I have tried this:

```
page {
    [treeLevel = 0]
      headerData.20.value = Home Page
    [END]
    [page|uid = 1]
      headerData.20.value = Page 1
    [END]
    [page|uid = 2]
      headerData.20.value = Page 2
    [END]
    [page|uid = 3]
      headerData.20.value = Page 3
    [END]
}
```

But the home page outputs `Page 3`

I have also tried `[globalVar = TSFE:id = X]` with the same result.

And the object Browser says `[` is an invalid character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#where-to-insert-conditions-in-typoscript) (*thanks to @BerndWilkeπφ for reminding*),  TypoScript conditions must be placed on top level of your TS (**outside** of any other structures).

Not in any cObject like `page`, neither within other conditions.

Comment: where to place conditions: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#where-to-insert-conditions-in-typoscript

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ that's what I mean, probably in the middle of the night, I'm a blind chicken! Thanks for pointing I'll update my answer.

Comment: And actually doc should be: _Conditions **must** be used outside of confinements (curly braces) only!_ The _**can**_ word sounds like optional to me although _only_ at the end + given samples clarifies it. However _**can**_ word at the beginning of this sentence is just tricky for the brain.

Answer (score 1):

I realised the problem is because I nested the conditions inside `page`.
After taking them out it all works fine.